# Python BS4 html parser response saved is different

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
response = requests.get("https://www.adidas.co.uk/gazelle-shoes/BB5478.html", headers=headers)
if response.status_code == 200:
    with open("response.html", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
        file.write(response.text)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    product_name_elem = soup.find('h1', class_='product-title')
I
```

am not able to get color or the sizes from the below url. It blocks with 10 second delay too.

Comment: it give 403 error using bs4, you have to use selenium

Answer (score 0):

You can use selenium for this site because site contain pop-up until and cookies so we have to close and accpet these pop up or cookies.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

service = Service(executable_path='/home/pixarsart/Downloads/chromedriver-linux64/chromedriver')
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
driver.get('https://www.adidas.co.uk/gazelle-shoes/BB5478.html')
title = driver.title[12:]

# click on accept pop button
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="glass-gdpr-default-consent-accept-button"]').click()
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
shoes_name = soup.find('h1').text
print(shoes_name)
driver.close()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot. still cannot get sizes some sizes are crossed or not available. pls check and let me know. i extracted through webscraper plugin. still trying to learn through python

Comment: size_selector_div = soup.find('div', {'class': 'size-selector___2kfnl'})
size_selector_html = str(size_selector_div) if size_selector_div else ""